# How to make SWF Call a Rails Ajax Request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, actionscript-2

I'm writing an application that requires a flv video to be watched before displaying a proceed button to the next section of the site.

Currently when the video ends the SWF player makes a POST request to the server marking the video as watched for the current user. Upon success the SWF player calls a Javascript function... Alert('Ajax Request Here')

**Option 1:**
When the video is done playing and a successful POST is made; the SWF player can call a javascript method (in place of current Alert) to make an AJAX request to an RJS file that would check to make sure all videos have been watched in the section and if so provide a proceed button.

*Can you wrap an AJAX call to an RJS file into a single javascript function that I could call from my SWF? If so how?*

**Option 2:** 
If it's possible to have a Controller method run an RJS file then I could make the original POST request run an RJS file for the current user. (Doesn't seem likely that this is possible since I'm not sure how the Server could communicate with the browser)

*Can a controller method call an RJS file? If so how?*

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Um, just make flash post directly to a url. Pass the flash some sort of token with params so that you can pass that back after so you can identify who watched the video.

The fact that rails is behind it should not matter.